# About action and method of form in html

Tags: html

I've encounter the below coding:

```
   <form id="frm" action="..." method="post">
```

I can't find any explanation of action="..." on the internet. Do you guys know what is that meaning?

Answer (score 1):

> The action attribute specifies where to send the form-data when a form
>   is submitted.
>
> http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp

For example

```
<form id="frm" action="/Foo/AddFoo" method="post">
```

**EDIT:**

`action="..."` is meaningless. There is no such page so it will cause 404 error.

Comment: I know that action attribute specifies where to send the form-data when a form is submitted. But the action of my form here is "...". What is it mean then?

Comment: @Coolguy, "..." it means you need to replace that one.

Comment: Replace? But my coding here is working fine with action="...". Why?

Comment: Are you handling the `$_POST` data on the same page? If yes, then it simply means that "..." is not a valid path and it would point to itself.

Comment: Yes. I think that it will be posting the form to itself.

Comment: @Coolguy, you would need to show your actual code for analysis if you think it is “working fine”. My bet would be that the form is not actually submitted at all but used client-side only.

Comment: @Coolguy It is not valid, form will not be posted to self in this case, it will be 404 instead as -Jukka K. Korpela told

Answer (score 1):

The value of `action attribute` is **invalid**, hence this `...` doesn't make any sense, if you are reading some tutorial, than the code probably means, replace `...` with a page name where you've written some code to process that form.

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
   <!-- Buttons and fields goes here -->
</form>
```

Comment: Technically, I think `action="..."` is valid, it just refers to something (a resource with the string `...` in its URL) that probably does not exist. Most probably `...` is just a placeholder in some tutorial, but if taken literally, `action="..."` should normally result just in 404 Not Found.

Answer (score 0):

action=" " is take you on page where you want to go..

like i have tow page 1. `myfirst.html` and 2. `mysecont.html`

in first i write `<form id="frm" action="mysecont.html" method="post">` then its take me on `mysecont.html` when we post form

in sort, **The action attributes tell the form where to post the form data to...**

**if you write `action=" "` then its post data on same page...**